# Twitter embedded timeline 100% width

Tags: html, css, twitter

I have a Twitter embedded timeline running on [this page](http://bit.ly/1eIKF2Y).

Via CSS, I've added the following class:

```
.twitter-timeline {
     min-width: 100% !important;
```

Up until yesterday, this CSS was successfully extending the timeline to the full width of the content area, but today the style does not work.

I can see that Twitter have the following style running within the iframe:

```
.timeline {
     max-width: 520px;
```

I assume this is something that Twitter have added recently. Is there anything I can do to overwrite this? I've tried adding the following to my CSS class, but it hasn't worked:

```
.twitter-timeline {
     min-width: 100% !important;
     width: 100% !important;
```

I'm aware that I can tap into the Twitter API to create a custom feed, but we do not have access to the artists Twitter account to generate access tokens etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned twitter currently does not allow for its timeline widget to get 100% width.  For responsive sites this is a pain but there is a solution (for now).

Use a callback on the twitter embed script and point it to a function that alters the iframe styles.

**Solution Using Jquery**

Replace you twitter embed code (under the `<a>` tag) with this.

```
            <script>
                    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
                        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
                            js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
                            js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                            js.setAttribute('onload', "twttr.events.bind('rendered',function(e) {responsiveTwitterWidget()});");
                            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
                        }}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");

                    function responsiveTwitterWidget(){
                        var widget = $("#twitter-widget-0");
                        var frame_style = widget.attr('style');
                        widget.attr('style', frame_style + ' max-width:none !important; width:100%');
                        if(widget) {
                            var head = widget.contents().find("head")
                            if (head.length) {
                                head.append('<style>.timeline { max-width: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; } .timeline .stream { max-width: none !important; width: 100% !important; }</style>');
                            }
                            widget.append($('<div class=timeline>'));
                        }
                    }
                </script>
```

Adjustments would need to be made if more than one timeline widget on a page.

May not wont work on some older IE browsers.

Answer (score 2):

We've found lately that Twitter's fairly new code generator for embedded profile timelines at [publish.twitter.com](https://publish.twitter.com) still creates the issue of the timeline overflowing the container width for iOS devices, particularly with width and height settings (and no data-tweet-limit set).

Having tried all of the javascript solutions above to maintain the timelime width=100% of the container, yet constrain the timeline to no more than the container width, we've done so via this added css (with selector potentially proceeded by your additional specificity, as needed):

`.twitter-timeline {
    width: 100vw !important;
}`

Note that you'll want to be sure the viewport is set, perhaps like so (but as appropriate for your implementation):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Note also the old shrink-to-fit=no hack no longer seems to have any effect in modern iOS

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

**CSS**

```
iframe[id^='twitter-widget-0'] {
     height:600px !important;
     margin-bottom:10px !important;
     width:100% !important;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
   $('iframe[id^=twitter-widget-]').each(function () {
      var head = $(this).contents().find('head');
          if (head.length) {
              head.append('<style>.timeline { max-width: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; } .timeline .stream { max-width: none !important; width: 100% !important; }</style>');
          }
          $('#twitter-widget-0').append($('<div class=timeline>'));
   })
});
```

Found this when surfing internet for the solution.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-create-full-width-twitter-timeline-on-responsive-page

Answer (score 1):

simple and works:

`$('.twitter-timeline').css({width: '100%'});`

Comment: In the future please write a bit more why this works and what this code does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript.

Here is a solution with jQuery :

```
$("iframe[id^='twitter-widget-']").contents().find(".timeline").css("maxWidth", "none");
```

Comment: I'm not certain this will work because the CSS class `.timeline` is hosted externally within the Twitter iFrame.

Comment: You probably need to wait until the iframe has loaded with something like `$("iframe[id^='twitter-widget-']").load(function () { /* put the code here */ });`

Comment: I'm working within WordPress so have included the following: `$(document).ready(function() {
 $("iframe[id^='twitter-widget-0']").load(function () { 
  $("iframe[id^='twitter-widget-0']").contents().find(".timeline").css("max-width", "none");
 });
});`. Still isn't working and the console isn't show any errors. Perhaps Twitter have restricted changes like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can append an external css file into the twitter iframe, the background should change to light blue with this example.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        function changeWidget() {
            var twFrame = $('iframe#twitter-widget-0');
            if (twFrame.length > 0) {
                twFrame.contents()
                .find('head').append('<link href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />');
            } else {
                setTimeout(changeWidget, 1500);
            }
        }
        changeWidget();
    });
</script>
```

Append your own css location containing:

```
 .timeline{
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], t = window.twttr || {};
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    t._e = [];
    t.ready = function(f) {
      t._e.push(f);
    };

    return t;
  }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

  twttr.ready(function(twttr) {
    $(".tweet").each(function() {
      twttr.widgets.createTweet($(this).data("id"), $(this)[0], {cards: "hidden"}).then(function(el) {
        $(el).contents().find('.EmbeddedTweet').css('max-width', '800px');
      }); 
    });
  });
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="tweet" data-id="705128887810965504"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually it worked for me, by just removing the `data-width` and `data-height` attributes from the `<a class="tweeter-timeline"`

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2...">
    <a class="twitter-timeline">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually break into their iFrame and modify the CSS yourself like so.

```
<body onload="onLoad()">

<script>

function onLoad() {
    var twitter_iframe = document.getElementById('twitter-widget-0');
    var twitter_document = twitter_iframe.contentDocument || twitter_iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var twitter_timeline = twitter_document.getElementsByClassName("timeline-Widget")[0];
    twitter_timeline.style = "left:0;right:0;margin:auto;padding:auto;min-width:100%;";
}

</script>
```

Note: Obviously this could stop working the road if they adjust their JS, but the good news is it won't break your page or anything, it will just simply go back to not having 100% width.

---

## Edit:

I've made a more robust attack on this as the twitter feed sometimes loads after body's onLoad is called. The following approach will grab those too for almost all cases:

```
    function onLoad() {
        resizeTwitterFeed();
        setTimeout(function(){ resizeTwitterFeed(); }, 100);
        setTimeout(function(){ resizeTwitterFeed(); }, 250);
        setTimeout(function(){ resizeTwitterFeed(); }, 500);
        setTimeout(function(){ resizeTwitterFeed(); }, 750);
        setTimeout(function(){ resizeTwitterFeed(); }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function(){ resizeTwitterFeed(); }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function(){ resizeTwitterFeed(); }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function(){ resizeTwitterFeed(); }, 5000);
        setTimeout(function(){ resizeTwitterFeed(); }, 10000);
    }
    
    function resizeTwitterFeed() {

        var twitter_iframe = document.getElementById('twitter-widget-0');
        if (twitter_iframe) {
            var twitter_document1 = twitter_iframe.contentDocument;
            if (twitter_document1) {
                var twitter_timeline1 = twitter_document1.getElementsByClassName("timeline-Widget")[0];
                if (twitter_timeline1) {
                    twitter_timeline1.style = "left:0;right:0;margin:auto;padding:auto;min-width:100%;";
                }
            }
            
            var twitter_document2 = twitter_iframe.contentWindow.document;
            if (twitter_document2) {
                var twitter_timeline2 = twitter_document2.getElementsByClassName("timeline-Widget")[0];
                if (twitter_timeline2) {
                    twitter_timeline2.style = "left:0;right:0;margin:auto;padding:auto;min-width:100%;";
                }
            }

            twitter_iframe.onload = function() {
                resizeTwitterFeed();
                return true;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I've verified this works, just tested it on my own embed.